# How to change date format on windows mobile phones?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I need my dates to be in U.S date format. How do I change it so when I do DateTime converts it does this format?

In asp.net I put some globalization thing in the web.config but got no clue when it comes to mobile phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use [DateTime.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326719(VS.71).aspx) and pass your own date format string or set the [culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(VS.71).aspx).